# PHP PDO Stopped Working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running into a weird issue with PDO.  Sometimes it just doesn’t execute the SQL.  But it acts like it does.

```
$SQL = 'INSERT INTO
beam_stats (beam_id, beam_stat_type, beam_stat_count)
                VALUES
                    (:BID, :BST, :BSC)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    beam_stat_count = beam_stat_count + VALUES(beam_stat_count)';
$parameters = Array(':BID' => $beamID, ':BST' => $valueName, ':BSC' => $value);
$this->dbCon->prepare_execute($SQL, $parameters);
    /**
     * Prepares and Executes the provided statement and parameters.
     *
     * @param string $statement
     * @param ARRAY $parameters
     * @return mixed database results
     */
    public function prepare_execute($statement, $parameters) {
        $this->prepare($statement);
        return $this->execute($parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Prepares the provided database statement
     *
     * @author  Jonathan Pitcher
     *
     * @param string $statement
     */
    public function prepare($statement) {
        $this->sth = $this->db->prepare($statement);

        if (!$this->sth) {
            error_log(print_r($this->db->errorInfo(), true));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes the prepared statement in sth using the passed parameters.
     *
     * @author Jonathan Pitcher
     *
     * @param ARRAY $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function execute($parameters) {
        $results = $this->sth->execute($parameters);
        $count = $this->sth->rowCount();
        error_log($this->sth->queryString);
        error_log("Updated $count rows.\n");
        if (!$results) {

            error_log(print_r($this->sth->errorInfo(), true));

            return false;
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

I log everything.  So when it executes the logs print out what happens and how many rows got updated.

```
[Thu Jun 05 10:15:40 2014] [error] [client ] Updating Beam Stat 494 sold_out 1
[Thu Jun 05 10:15:40 2014] [error] [client ] INSERT INTO\n\t\t\t\t\t\tbeam_stats (beam_id, beam_stat_type, beam_stat_count)\n\t\t\t\t\tVALUES\n\t\t\t\t\t\t(:BID, :BST, :BSC)\n\t\t\t\t\tON     DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n\t\t\t\t\t\tbeam_stat_count = beam_stat_count + VALUES(beam_stat_count)
[Thu Jun 05 10:15:40 2014] [error] [client ] Updated 1 rows.\n
```

But when I check the database the line has not been inserted.

Now if I copy the SQL and the values and run it manually it works.

And if a record is already in there it works it will update the total.  But it will not insert the record.

To make it even weirder this sql is a function used all over the site and it works with no issues anywhere else.  Just this one scenario.

Comment: Looks like you are not sending this array as a parameter to your `execute` method, your error message suggests that the query still has placeholders in it

Comment: How do you execute this statement?

Comment: What's the point with beam_stat_count + VALUES(beam_stat_count) ? But show us HOW you execute the array and how you handle the execution.

Comment: Sadly PDO does not show you the actual query that was sent to the server.  What is printed out is the best you can see before it is sent off to the server which is $sth->queryString

Comment: Jonast92 The point of beam_stat_count + VALUES(beam_stat_count)is to increment the value of the field by the amount passed.  So if the value was 15 and I passed 35, the new value would now be 50

Comment: @JonathanPitcher You have a capital letter in your array `$parameters = Array(...)` it should be `array()`. fix this please

Comment: It was a transaction issue. We had an open transaction call on another set of logic that never got rolled back when the results failed earlier.

So make sure to turn on your query logging and to check what is coming through before the command you are having issues with.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

your parameter array is incorrect. It should be `'BID'`,`'BST'`,`'BSC'` that is, drop the colon `:` for the parameter array.

Comment: Wrong, you should not skip the colon. From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php): $sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));

Comment: @serakfalcon Those colons are fine even inside the array. See this PHP.net example: `$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));`

Comment: hmm maybe i got it confused with the DBL i normally use

Comment: they are optional on the execute array, but they are required in the query string